# Simple REGEX to print specific entries from a string

Tags: regex, pcre, freeswitch, logfile, substring

I have a log file which is full of entries like the one below:

```
2017-07-13 11:23:43.717948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1713 SRC=7479569217;7479569217;768733974848304;7479569217;300067;333;-1
```

I'm trying to print specific values between `;` which are numeric (always). For example, I want to print the 1st, 3rd and 5th number between `;`.

I tried this pattern:

```
(?=;).+?(?=;).+?.+?(?=;)
```

It will print the 2nd and the 3rd. Not sure how to print for example the 2nd and the 4th without also print the 3rd...

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I was not clear enough or the example was not in its best form. So let me add some more info to it:

```
2017-07-13 11:23:43.717948 [CRIT] mod_dptools.c:1713 SRC=123;1234567890;00000000;2222222;7479569217;87654321;300067;333;-1
```

My expected output is: `123;00000000;7479569217;300067;333;-1`

That means the 1st number, then the 3rd, the 5th, the 6th, the 7th, then the 8th.

Best would be to able to select later if I need changes, like printing the 2nd, the 3rd, the 4th and the 5th entry only.

Comment: What are the expected matches? Maybe you want [`\d+(?=;|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/aPxErv/1)?

Comment: `768733974848304;7479569217;300067;333;-1` let's say I only need to print those

Comment: [`-?\d+(?:;-?\d+){4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/aPxErv/2)?

Comment: Or even: [`(?<=[;=])-?\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/armiD6/1)?

Comment: I have edited my question and provided more details. Thank you both for your answer. The 1st one works but it's not exactly what I need; the 2nd one displays nothing. I'm using the online regex tool from regex101

Comment: according to regex101 the default selected is pcre/php

Comment: What I meant is in what regex flavor / language you're writing your program?

Comment: I intend to use it in freeswitch in the config file which is formatted XML style but I suppose it's using PCRE

Comment: [You can probably use this regex with multiple groups](https://regex101.com/r/HGKhdB/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trust the data in your logfile and you don't want to validate your values to only contain `-` and numbers, then you can just use a negated character class containing `;` (this will improve pattern efficiency) and only parenthetically wrap the values that you want.

Pattern:  ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/do4xaE/1))

```
#not captured--vv------------vv
     =([^;]*;)[^;]*;([^;]*;)[^;]*;([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)([^;]*;)(.*)
         $1            $2            $3      $4      $5      $6    $7
```

Notice that the last capture group (`$7`) uses a dot instead of a negative character class.  This is so the pattern does not try to match on the next line. I assume this is an important feature because your logfile will have many lines of data in it. (if not, the final capture group can be like the others before it)

I am using `*` as a zero-or-more quantifier, in case the logfile can deliver empty values between the semicolons.  If the logfile always contains a number for each value, then `+` can be used as a quantifier.

If you need to validate the values, Usagi's pattern is suitable.

Consolidating my capture groups like this: `=([^;]*;)[^;]*;([^;]*;)[^;]*;([^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;.*)` or `=([^;]*;)[^;]*;([^;]*;)[^;]*;((?:[^;]*;){4}.*)` successfully reduces the total number of capture groups and improves pattern efficiency & brevity, but makes the pattern slightly harder to update in the future.  A more verbose pattern will make capture group changing a snap.  It is up to you which pattern to select based on Validation, Efficiency, Brevity, and Maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
=(-?\d+;)-?\d+;(-?\d+);-?\d+(;-?\d+)(;-?\d+)(;-?\d+)(;-?\d+)(;-?\d+)
```

### Edited

Did not noticed the negative sign...

Comment: Your regular expression does not match the subject string.
QUICK REFERENCE. Show nothing... You might have a typo in the regex I believe

Comment: @BogdanStoica I think he meant: [`=(\d+);\d+;(\d+);\d+;((?:-?\d+;?){5})\K`](https://regex101.com/r/isIsbz/1) ... BTW, I added the `\K` just to illustrate better his idea.